# Protect api routes with tokens in a laravel - Angular application

Tags: angular, access-token, angular-routing, laravel-passport, laravel-5.6

I'm working on a application with laravel backend for API and angular for frontend. Data is feed to frontend from this API. **No login** (still). I want to keep these data feeding urls(routes) secure. No body cannot be access from outside. I refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43951740/laravel-5-4-how-to-protect-api-routes) and something called [api-guard](https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard).  I think there is a way of doing this in a comment of that quiz. (I think this is the way. if there is anything else as the solution, feel free to mention it)  as

> use laravel passport and create a client then use Bearer $token in header for each request and passport middleware will handle it for protection -  [@msonowal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1125961/msonowal)

But still I have no idea how to do that. If a user enter to the site, how to

- generate token to request
- append it to url
- verify it from backend
- response back relevant to that request (is there any response token append to response)

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 2):

You can create a personal access token (Refer laravel\passport documentation)
that's the simplest method as you are yet to implement login

or

You can generate token for each user during the login

```
$token = Auth::user()->createToken('Access Token')->accessToken;
```

this generates a user specific token
return this token value in the login success response

whichever method you chose you can pass it as Bearer your-token  as authorization header for each request

you can use the middleware to check authentication in your routes/api.php

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () {
     // Routes that need authentication here
 }
```

Comment: login means entering username, password or just entering to the site. 
Until login integration, is this createToken method can protect the requests in normal site surfing ?